# How to group some location coordinates in Philadelphia (2 million approx.) on the basis of postal codes using reverse geocoding?

Tags: python, google-maps, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

Simply querying 2 million coordinates on google geocoder or nominatim is going to take an eternity and I would most likely be blocked due to the huge quantity of requests.

Here's one thought.

- Randomly geocoding some 1000 coordinates in my dataset (all coordinates are located in Philadelphia).
- Then running each and every coordinate in my dataset to calculate the minimum distance between the 1000 calculated location coordinates.
- Storing the postal code of the location for which distance is minimum.

Is there any other practical way by which I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option: If you want to group them by post code, get the zip code polygons (ZTA polygons can be gotten from the census bureau), do point in polygon analysis of the coordinates in your database to classify them by zip code.  Doesn't require Google's services.